# Map unable to create seperate paragraph tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to use map on an array of string to get multiple paragraphs preceded by headers, however all the strings wind up in the same paragraph tag. I expect

```
<h3> Header 1 </h3>
<p> String 1 </p>
<h3> Header 2 </h3>
<p> String 2 </p>
```

,but get

```
<h3> Header 1 </h3>
<p> String 1String 2  </p>
<h3> Header 2 </h3>
```

The incoming list seems fine and replacing the string in the map with a constant fixed the issue. Below is the function in question.

```
function instructionsRenderer(subtasks, element_name)
{
        var elements = [subtasks.map((subtask) => subtask['data']['text'])]
        console.log(elements)
        var zipElems = zip(INSTRUCTIONS_SUBTASKS,elements)
        /*const dispElem = zipElems.map((elem) => <div>
                <h3> {elem[0]} </h3>
                <p> {elem[1]} </p>
                </div>)*/
        const dispElem = elements.map((elem) => <p> {elem} </p>)

        console.log(dispElem)
        return(
        <Collapsible element={<div> {dispElem} </div>} element_name={element_name}/>
        );
}
```

Comment: try adding a key in `p` where it is being mapped

Comment: Adding a key which used the index didn't help. Just to be sure I understood correctly, I wrote: "arr.map( (str,idx) => <p key={idx}> {str} </p>)"

Comment: Can you put here the output of `console.log(elements)` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your method to this, I guess `elements` array only has one item.

```
function instructionsRenderer(subtasks, element_name)
{
        // .map will return an array
        var elements = subtasks.map((subtask) => subtask['data']['text'])
        console.log(elements)

        var zipElems = zip(INSTRUCTIONS_SUBTASKS,elements)
        /*const dispElem = zipElems.map((elem) => <div>
                <h3> {elem[0]} </h3>
                <p> {elem[1]} </p>
                </div>)*/
        const dispElem = elements.map((elem) => <p> {elem} </p>)

        console.log(dispElem)
        return(
        <Collapsible element={<div> {dispElem} </div>} element_name={element_name}/>
        );
}
```

Comment: You are right that there is only one element, but this isn't a solution to my problem. I don't understand why there is just one element though. The subtasks element is an array of size 4, however elements is of length 1, but contains 4 strings. Is it normal that JS combines strings it that way?

Comment: Try the above solution. I have removed the `[]` before subtasks.map because it itself is an array

Comment: You're right, I hadn't noticed that the output was being put in an array. I did wind up going with another solution, but I'll accept this one. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As Faisal pointed out, the length of the string array was different (1 rather than 4). The old code had  square brackets around map, which was the issue.

Iterating through the original array (substasks) rather than the array of strings fixed the issue and resulted in more compact code.

```
const dispElem = subtasks.map((subtask,idx) => <div onClick={() => setSelect(subtask['id'])}>
                <h3> {subtask['id']} </h3>
                <p key={idx}> {subtask['data']['text']} </p>
                </div>)
        return(
        <Collapsible element={<div> {dispElem} </div>} element_name={element_name}/>
        );
```